# LatexIt: how to include code?

Tags: mactex, latexit

I am trying to use LatexIt for code inclusion in the presentation (keynote). I have added the `\usepackage{listings}` in the `body templates => preamble` and the MWE* is here:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
public class test{
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

So, when I try to "Latex it!" it gives errors:

```
Missing $ inserted.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Missing } inserted.
Missing } inserted.
```

and so on.

Any tips?

*Should be MNWE = Minimal Not Working Example.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think `latexit` is meant for inserting formulas IIRC.

Comment: I don't think LaTeXIt is meant for general LaTeX compilation; it does formulas, that's all.

Comment: Your example works for me with the latest version of LaTeXIt (2.5.4). A possible problem with your example might be that you have to select text.

Comment: @egreg LaTeXIt can pretty well be used for general LaTeX compilation as long as the result is just a single page. I have used it quite a lot for including TikZ images and listings into my Keynote presentations. The point is the body/preamble templates, which have to be set up to include the respective packages.

Comment: Your example works well here, please provide us the complete preamble template and body.

Comment: @Daniel added the screenshot. Even when selecting the text it gives me the same error.

Comment: After changing the template for the preamble you have to click the apply button, and you have to select `text`. Also you can consider to upgrade to the last version.

Comment: @Guido have done exactly that. I have the latest version of LatexIt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MWE seems to works properly.

[image]

After changing the preamble one has to apply it to the open document, and then complying using text. The screenshot in the original post indicates  that one of the other options is used (Align, which is in math mode)

Comment: is your ``texlive`` version ``2013``?

Comment: My distribution is texlive 2013. But I have downloaded version 2.5.4 from the LaTeXIt (go to Check for Updates menu item)

Comment: Really strange, we have the same version of the software (I am on Mavericks).

Comment: The version of LaTeXIt that ships with MacTeX/texlive is not the latest stable version. The latest stable version is 2.5.4. Also, I get your result when I do not select `Text`.

Comment: I have 2.5.4. I think LatexIt asked me if I wanted to update and so did I. I have got two macs (pro and air) -- the same problem in both.

Comment: In your screenshot you use `Align`. What do you get if you use `Text`?

Comment: Really strange, yesterday, I tried all of the options -- it did not work, now when I changed to align it actually *works*!!! Thank you.